# elasticsearch in a single page application

Tags: ruby, ember.js, sinatra, elasticsearch

I am looking for some high level advice on the following:

I want to use elasticsearch in an ember.js single page application.

I have a sinatra application which is the API layer for this application.

What would be the best way of utilising elasticsearch?

Should I create a proxy layer in the sinatra application that creates elasticsearch queries and transforms the results into the appropriate ember.js models?

I don't think that querying the elasticsearch API directly is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both might be valid approaches but I would say you better stick with the sinatra "proxy".
Here are some reasons:

- Easier to change implementation of the search engine. Maybe you want to use Solr later on?
- Control usage
- ElasticSearch is like a database. Do you want to give direct access to the end user?
- What if you want to monitor the search your users make? With sinatra in the middle this is really easy.